# Building java exe file with launch4J has error : "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NoResultException

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I'm trying to produce a .exe file from my application.
It works correctly on Netbeans but I can't generate the .exe file.
 this is the error:

> Blockquote

```
Executing: D:\dev\tools\stock_exchange\stock_exchange\src\App\MarketSimulator.exe
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NoResultException
    at org.stock.simulator.view.Home.<init>(Home.java:28)
    at org.stock.simulator.view.Home$11.run(Home.java:822)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NoResultException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

This is my library structure:
[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your .exe can't find the class.
This is probably due to the way you exported your project as a runnable JAR.

There are a couple of ways to export to a runnable JAR, but you can for example :

1. Export the project with the libraries in a separate folder next to your JAR
   *--> Easy to replace library versions, but not the cleanest or most portable solution. Since you always have to include a separate folder with your .exe*
2. Export the project with the libraries extracted into your JAR
   *--> This is more portable than 1., but can possible create a lot packages and source code within the JAR*
3. Export the project with the libraries packaged into your JAR
   *--> This is more portable than 1. and allows for an easier library replace than 2.*

Since both option 2 and 3 have the necessary libraries included within the JAR, I would think that you have used something like option1.

If you add the necessary libraries in the same folder as the generated .exe, it should execute correctly.

If this doesn't explain your problem or you went with a different approach,
then please update your question with the necessary information and we'll help you further.

Comment: Hello thanks, for your answer. What I did is option 2.It works on my computer but not in other computer. I have even export my javaBundle(jre) in the setup folder I create...